# Rxdb Plugin: Using the RxCollectionBase#insert method in a plugin

Tags: rxdb

I am trying to create a plugin for rxdb.
I want to catch the exception raised by `insert` and return an hash with
`{[fieldName: string] => [error:string]}`

When using my new method though, I am getting an exception, and it seems like the method is getting called directly on the prototype rather than on each `RxColletion<T, T2, T3>` instance.

The error i am getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fillObjectWithDefaults' of undefined
```

which happens here: https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/blob/ac9fc95b0eda276110f371afca985f949275c3f1/src/rx-collection.ts#L443

because `this.schema` is undefined.. The collection I am running this method on does have a schema though..

Here is my plugin code:

```js
export const validatedInsertPlugin: RxPlugin = {
    rxdb: true,
    prototypes: {
        RxCollection(proto: IRxCollectionBaseWithValidatedInsert) {
            proto.validatedInsert = async function validatedInsert<T, D>(
                doc: T
            ): Promise<Insert<T>> {
                try {
                    // this is the line that raises:
                    const product = await proto.insert(doc);
                    return [true, product];
                } catch (e) {
                    // extract errors
                    return [false, {} as Errors<T>];
                }
            };
        },
    },
    overwritable: {},
    hooks: {},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question,

`proto.insert` is targeting the prototype, which is not what I want.
`function(this: RxCollection)` is what I want. I have to use `this` which will target the actual instance.

```
proto.validatedInsert = async function validatedInsert<T1>(
                this: RxCollection,
                doc: T1
            ): Promise<ValidatedInsert<T1>> {
                try {
                    const product = await this.insert(doc); // this, not proto
                    return [true, product];
                } catch (e) {
    ...
```